# Nav Menu Not Dropping Down Correctly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a site and I need to get the top menu to create a drop down menu. I already have the elements hanging out in the site, but I have put `display:none` in the ul for the list items I need (found under the Services link). If you remove it, the drop down menu will show when hovering over the Services link. When that happens, I have the drop down list pushing the menu off to the side when I need it to just drop down. Any suggestions? I'm fighting the native CSS for the site's template between 4 stylesheets and I'm at my wit's end here.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've narrowed it down to what CSS stylesheet is causing the issue. I'm pretty sure it's the main stylesheet at this point (style.css).

Comment: Try changing the dropdown's `position:` to `absolute`.

Comment: No luck so far. There is no dropdown class listed in the HTML document for the nav area that I can see, so that might explain why it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Well since it's using bootstrap you can embed dropdown menus inside a nav. [Bootstrap Nav](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your case it will be easier to explain how to do this rather than try and pick your site apart and see what's wrong (quick notices were: `ul` is not positioned and there seems to be no hover action to display it).

Here is your structure rebuilt (class names are different, etc. but its the same format):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="link">
        <a href="#">Hover over Me</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li>subnav 1</li>
            <li>subnav 1</li>
            <li>subnav 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

What you need to do is style the subnav's wrapper, which is the `ul`. You need to set it to `position: absolute` and `display: none`. Position absolute will remove it from the flow of the document so that it will not effect the rest of your nav items when you display it:

```
ul.subnav{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background: blue;
   color: #FFF;
}
```

But `absolute` images are by nature relative to the document so to contain this subnav you'll need to set it's parent (the `li`) to `position: relative` so that it contains this element:

```
li.link{
   position: relative;
}
```

Lastly you can show your hidden menu on a `:hover` state of the parent:

```
.link:hover .subnav{
   display:block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0guzdfg2/)